# Method for avoiding duplicates when generating a random list of pairs of numbers is not working as it should

Tags: java

I have this code for setting random values to true in a boolean[][], without making any duplicates:

```
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<=50; i++) {                                         
        do {
            a = randomizer.nextInt(hoogte);                                 
            b = randomizer.nextInt(breedte);    
            /**debug variable*/
            counter++;
        } while (bommaker[a][b]);

        bommaker[a][b] = true; 
    }
```

After testing for a while, I noticed something was wrong, so I added a counter to check it. Every time I run the program, there comes a different number out of "counter". One time it was 57 while the other time even 63. But I have set the loop to exactly 51. This means the code isn't working as it should. Can somebody explain why it generates more than 51 numbers, and give a possible solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to remember that you have a loop within a loop. The OUTTER loop is limited to 51 executions, but the inner loop will cause a random number of iterations (an extra iteration for each time it sees that the array has already been set to true).

Other than the counter value being greater than you expected, what about the code is not working?

Comment: I need it to be the number I set. Is there a way I can inspect the variable while the program is running in eclipse?

Comment: You need what to be the number you set? The counter? If all you care about is that the counter is 51, put the increment outside the inner loop and just count the number of times your array was updated. Yes, use Debug instead of Run and set a breakpoint.

Comment: If you want to really get a feel for what is going on, use the following: `System.out.println(String.format("got a=%d and b=%d", a,b));` in the inner loop and `System.out.println(String.format("Setting array at a=%d and b=%d to true", a,b));` in the outter loop. This will probably be more efficient than using a debugger as you won't have to keep track of every a & b as you step through. However, if you have not used a debugger before, definitely try it.

Comment: Thanks, is this possible in Android as well? Can you just print things? And I did debug before, but not in eclipse. In the top right corner there is a debug "tab". But I want to be able to inspect all variables, as I used to do in BlueJ.

Comment: Not sure about Android, have not done it. To kick off the debugger, use "Debug As..." instead of "Run As..." to start it off. This should automatically ask you if you want to switch to the Debug perspective (the debug tab).

Comment: Thanks. It appereared to be an other problem with my code. The debugging really helped.

Answer (score 0):

move out the counter++ line from do while loop

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int counter = 0;

for (int i=0; i<=50; i++) {                                         
    do {
        a = randomizer.nextInt(hoogte);                                 
        b = randomizer.nextInt(breedte);    
        /**debug variable*/
    } while (bommaker[a][b]);

    counter++;

    bommaker[a][b] = true; 
}
```

Comment: That may work for the counter, it gets indeed 51, but I want to make sure there are 51 values true. Because then there may be something else wrong with my code. But how can I inspect that within eclipse?

Comment: I would say that the best way to ensure that 51 values are true is to create another loop AFTER your for loop that goes through the entire array and counts the number of values that are set to true.